# How to change a value assigned to a variable into integer in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to compare two filesystem values `/var` and `/tmp` and as per the result need to execute the corresponding remediation playbook.

```yaml
- name: check top utilized files.
  shell: du -sx --exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys* --exclude=/dev* --exclude=/u02* --exclude=/usr* --exclude=/boot* --exclude=/swapfile* --exclude=/run* -t 200M "{{fs_input}}"* | sort -n -r
  register: top_files

- debug:
    msg: "{{ top_files.stdout_lines }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.split('\t/')[0]}}"
  with_items: "{{ top_files.stdout_lines[0] }}"
  register: value1

- debug:
    msg: "{{ value1 |int * 1024 }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.split('\t/')[0]}}"
  with_items: "{{ top_files.stdout_lines[1] }}"
  register: value2

- debug:
    msg: "{{ value2 |int * 1024 }}"
```

The debug value gives `0` as output.

Comment: What does `top_files.stdout_lines` prints you?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on here. `register` saves the result of a task, but you are trying to treat the registered variable as though it contains the single value you want. You're looping over single items, which will make the registered result more complicated than it needs to be.

`debug` + `register` is not a good way to do variable manipulation, but you can make it work:

```
# Removing the unnecessary loop
- debug:
    msg: "{{ top_files.stdout_lines.0.split('\t/')[0] }}"
  register: value1

- debug:
    msg: "{{ value1.msg | int * 1024 }}"

# Or you can leave it in, if you really want
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.split('\t/')[0]}}"
  loop:
    - "{{ top_files.stdout_lines[1] }}"
  register: value2

- debug:
    msg: "{{ value2.results.0.msg | int * 1024 }}"
```

However, it's better to use the Ansible features that are actually intended for this type of work.

```
- set_fact:
    value1: "{{ top_files.stdout_lines.0.split('\t/')[0] }}"
    value2: "{{ top_files.stdout_lines.1.split('\t/')[0] }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ value1 | int * 1024 }} / {{ value2 | int * 1024 }}"
```

or

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ value1 | int * 1024 }} / {{ value2 | int * 1024 }}"
  vars:
    value1: "{{ top_files.stdout_lines.0.split('\t/')[0] }}"
    value2: "{{ top_files.stdout_lines.1.split('\t/')[0] }}"
```

Personally, I might write it more like this:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ values.0 | int * 1024 }} / {{ values.1 | int * 1024 }}"
  vars:
    values: "{{ top_files.stdout_lines | map('split', '\t/') | map('first') }}"
```